# How do I store my contacts so I can retrieve them after a factory reset?

Tags: htc, htc-one-m8

Has anyone used the [HTC backup](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-one/howto/365635.html) app?

I'm going to factory reset my phone and I want to store my contacts somewhere so I can retrieve them after the reset.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't your contacts automatically synced with your Google account? Htc one m8 usually has Andorid 4.4 so you should check settings>accounts and check if your google account syncs your contact info automatically. You should double check it by logging to your google account on a computer to see if it's working.

Link to contacts: www.google.com/contacts

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Super Backup : SMS & Contacts - you can back up your contacts (and other data), back them up AND email it to yourself.  That way you have a safe copy you can then re-install easily.

I have used it very successfully when changing phones, but it's a great app anyway.